# Lots of mysql Sleep processes

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

I am still having trouble with my mysql server. It seems that since i optimize it, the tables were growing and now sometimes is very slow again. I have no idea of how to optimize more.

mySQL server has 48GB of RAM and mysqld is using about 8, most of the tables are innoDB.

Site has about 2000 users online. I also run explain on every query and every one of them is indexed.

mySQL processes:
http://www.pik.ba/mysqlStanje.php

my.cnf:

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
language        = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 10.100.27.30
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 64M
key_buffer_size = 512M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 128K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover          = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1000
table_cache            = 1000
join_buffer_size        = 2M
tmp_table_size          = 2G
max_heap_table_size     = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 128M
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
log-slow-queries        = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
sort_buffer_size        = 5M
net_buffer_length       = 5M
read_buffer_size        = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 12M
thread_concurrency     = 10
ft_min_word_len = 3
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 512M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
#log            = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#
# Error logging goes to syslog. This is a Debian improvement :)
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * BerkeleyDB
#
# Using BerkeleyDB is now discouraged as its support will cease in 5.1.12.
skip-bdb
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
# You might want to disable InnoDB to shrink the mysqld process by circa 100MB.
#skip-innodb
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * NDB Cluster
#
# See /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-*/README.Debian for more information.
#
# The following configuration is read by the NDB Data Nodes (ndbd processes)
# not from the NDB Management Nodes (ndb_mgmd processes).
#
# [MYSQL_CLUSTER]
# ndb-connectstring=127.0.0.1


#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: just out of context, how did you generate this mySQL process PHP page?

Comment: Please also post SHOW CREATE TABLE here because we need to see how optimal your indexes are

Comment: Can you give us more information about the server in general? Virtualised? Operating System, Swap, IO statistics, network statistics etc. Set-up of the application.

Comment: Tables are growing probably because you switched from MyIsam to innoDB in your optimization. InnoDB tables are larger than myisam tables. Have you enabled slow query logging? that might throw up something interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I refreshed on your process list page a couple times and quite often the queries I saw included "SELECT tablename.*"

Do you need every column from that table?  If not that could help.

Unless your server is strapped for resources I wouldn't worry a whole lot about sleeping processes.  They typically don't consume a lot of resources. However if you really do wish to manually set the amount of time before they are killed you can do the following in your config file:

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout=20
```